# Merge applications in Android

Tags: android, merge

I have two application in the android market that I would like to merge into one.

Now I've already started merging them, but the problem is both my applications costs money. If I am to merge them into one, people from the other application would have to pay back if they are to download the merged one.

I can refund them of course, but I'm looking for a way to make them do the transfer without any cost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to post your request at the [Android Market forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/label?lid=7dc8a5c590cd22ee&hl=en). Your other option would be to upload the same app under different packages at the same time.